# Permission denied on /dev/stderr after sudo

Tags: sudo

I use this command regularly to switch between users in my development VM:

```
✸ sudo su - otheruser
```

However I run into trouble if I try to access `/dev/stderr` or similar:

```
otheruser$ echo hi > /dev/stderr
-bash: /dev/stderr: Permission denied
```

I know that I could use `>&2` in this specific instance, but there are cases (such as `tee /dev/stderr`) where you need an openable file, not just a file descriptor.

I've figured out that I can open up write permission on the tty to work around this, before sudo:

```
✸ ls -ld /dev/stderr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 13 08:06 /dev/stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
✸ ls -ld /proc/self/fd/2
lrwx------ 1 aron aron 64 Jan 14 15:08 /proc/self/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/13
✸ ls -ld /dev/pts/13
crw--w---- 1 aron tty 136, 13 Jan 14 15:08 /dev/pts/13
✸ chmod a+w /dev/pts/13
```

or more simply:

```
✸ chmod a+w /dev/stderr
```

But I'm wondering if there's a different invocation I should be using, something that would properly allocate and/or grant permissions. Suggestions?

Comment: Currently using `perl -pe 'print STDERR'` as a replacement for `tee /dev/stderr` since it works directly with file descriptors instead of needing to reopen the tty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known quirk of the Linux implementation of /proc; one that [never got fixed](http://web.archive.org/web/20111011030303/http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/proc_self_fd.html) for many years. With Linux, opening the links under `/proc/*/fd/*` doesn't directly duplicate the file descriptor like dup() would (though the magic /proc links *could* achieve that in theory) – instead it opens the file anew, and will perform a new permission check.

The most basic workaround as you've found out is to grant the target user permissions on your tty before using `su` or `sudo`. For example:

```
userA$  setfacl -m u:userB:rw /dev/stderr
userA$  sudo -i -u userB
```

(It would probably be possible to write a PAM module which does the same.)

A probably better workaround is to use user-switching methods that give you a completely new tty – one such tool is `su --pty` if you have the util-linux version of su. Systemd has a `systemd-run` tool that can run temporary *services* interactively; and similarly it comes with a `machinectl shell` tool which is primarily meant for use with containers, but recent versions also have a "loopback" mode:

```
userA$  sudo su -l -P userB

userA$  sudo systemd-run --uid=userB --shell --quiet --collect

userA$  sudo machinectl shell userB@
```

You would also get the same result as a side-effect of using *terminal multiplexers* such as Screen or tmux, which necessarily allocate new ttys for their windows/panes:

```
userA$  sudo -u userB tmux
```

All these tools will allocate a new pty for the nested session, relaying all input/output between the two sides.

Comment: This answer is fantastic, thank you. Love tracking this back to Ted T'so's post. Fabulous.